# Can we fix clan war between two clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In clash of clans, if there is a clan whose members' strength is almost equal to our clan members and they both start war at the same time with equal members.

Is there any possibility by which both clans get in war ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to manually choose your opponent or skip opponents, the system will detect all clans matching your clans requirements and choose one of them. So if you're lucky you'll maybe be playing against the mentioned clan, although the chance is close to zero.

If you could choose your opponents there would probably be people abusing the system and boosting (Create 2 clans, let one clan win, then the other etc.)